# Backend crashes without an error while deleting from Mongo

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, react-hooks

First question ever, don't know what to search to find a solution, so here you go.

I'm using React, Mongo, Express, Node.

PatientDetails.js

This is how I fetch a specific patient when opening the details card.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/api/patients/${match.params.id}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => setPatient(json))

}, [patient])
```

This is how I delete a comment on the patient details card with an onclick method.

```
const deleteNote = (noteID) => {
    fetch(`/api/patients/${patient._id}/notes/${noteID}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
};
```

This is my API route.

```
// @route DELETE api/patients/:id/notes/:noteId
// @desc Delete a note

router.delete('/:id/notes/:noteId', async (req, res) => {
    const {id, noteId} = req.params
    await Patient.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$pull: {notes: noteId}});
    await Note.findByIdAndRemove(noteId);
})
```

I am able to delete like 3-4 comments before the page just ends up loading forever, I get no error on the frontend or back-end and I have to restart my backend server, then I am able to delete 3-4 more comments before this happens again.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I feel that - fetching the patient details would be a one-time event when the component mounts. So, you won't need `patient` as dependencies to `useEffect`

Comment: Are you getting timeout from the backend after which you have to restart the server?

Comment: DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout

Same thing happens after I tried removing [patients] as a dependency, but in general, Im getting no errors at all, the backend just stops sending data, or frontend stops fetching, one of the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some issues both in front-end and back-end:

In the React component you should add `match.params.id` as a dependency of the hook:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/api/patients/${match.params.id}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => setPatient(json))

}, [match.params.id])
```

In the Express middleware, you should send a response after modifying the database:

```js
router.delete('/:id/notes/:noteId', async (req, res) => {
    const {id, noteId} = req.params
    await Patient.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$pull: {notes: noteId}});
    await Note.findByIdAndRemove(noteId);
    res.status(200).send({});
})
```

Comment: Hey, this seems to have fixed my issue. The problem was with not sending status 200 after modifying the database, the match.params.id was irrelevant and it didnt update my component when deleting. It works perfect with the express middleware solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! :) Note that the usage of match.params.id in the hook is not related to update the component after deleting. It produces the hook being executed again when the url changes. If you want to do something when the delete request finishes, you should add that logic after the `deleteNote` promise is resolved.